# Guys, I really need help. When I run this program and put input, the value always returns zero. I am new to java

Tags: int, java.util.scanner, return-value

> When I run this program and put numbers, the program returns 0

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumOfNumberDigitsProgram
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner addDigits = new Scanner(System.in);
        int firstNum = 0;
        int secNum = 0;
        int thirdNum = 0;
        int forthNum = 0;
        int fifthNum = 0;
        System.out.println("This is Sum of Number Digits Program.");
        System.out.print("Enter an integer:");
        int sum = addDigits.nextInt();
        sum = computeSum(firstNum, secNum, thirdNum, forthNum, fifthNum);
        System.out.println("The sum of the digits of the Integer is " + sum + ".");
    }
```

> I think the problem is here

```
    public static int computeSum(int num1,int num2,int num3,int num4,int num5) 
    {
        int sum;
        sum = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5;
        return sum;
    }
}
```

> I am out of ideas now
>   Blockquote

Comment: I think everyone might be working properly. You are summing `0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0` which equals zero. Try changing the inputs.

Comment: `int sum = addDigits.nextInt();` assigns the input to `sum`. The next statement `sum = computeSum(firstNum, secNum, thirdNum, forthNum, fifthNum);` overwrites `sum` with the sum of all these variables that are still zero.